# Visual Studio 2019 is raising warnings about structures having variables without default values

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2019

Take this structure definition:

```cpp
typedef struct tagReferenceMWB
{
    COleDateTime datStartDate;
    COleDateTime datEndDate;
    COleDateTime datFirstMonday;
    COleDateTime datLastMonday;
    CString      strFileMWB;
    WORD         wCount;
    bool         bReferenced;
    bool         bModified;

} S_REFERENCE_MWB;
```

The compiler in VS2019 is issuing a warning:

[image: Warning]

> ```
> Warning   C26495  Variable 'CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::tagReferenceMWB::bModified' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    Meeting Schedule Assistant  d:\my programs\2019\meetschedassist\meeting schedule assistant\christianlifeministrydefines.h   348 
> Warning   C26495  Variable 'CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::tagReferenceMWB::bReferenced' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  Meeting Schedule Assistant  d:\my programs\2019\meetschedassist\meeting schedule assistant\christianlifeministrydefines.h   348 
> Warning   C26495  Variable 'CChristianLifeMinistryDefines::tagReferenceMWB::wCount' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).       Meeting Schedule Assistant  d:\my programs\2019\meetschedassist\meeting schedule assistant\christianlifeministrydefines.h   348
> ```

Since we can't assign default values in a structure definition how do we resolve the issue?

## Update

Based on the comments in the supplied answer I have check my project settings:

[image: C++ Language]

My project started life over 10 years ago and this setting appears to be **empty**. I do not know the significance is of this being left blank? These are the options I have:

[image: C++ Language Options]

What is the significant impact of changing the value to **C++14** or **C++17**? IE. will it affect what operating systems it can run on?

Comment: Changing the language standard has no effect on the platform the compiled code is going to run on. The target platform is controlled through preprocessor symbols (see [using the Windows headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/using-the-windows-headers)), as well as the toolset in use.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. I ended up changing it to C++17. Still compiled with no errors.

Comment: As an aside, the `typedef struct tagX {} X;` pattern is unnecessary in C++. This is a holdover from C, where, if you wanted to create an instance of `tagX`, you'd have to write `struct tagX x;`. In C++ you can simply say `tagX x;`, without repeating the `struct` keyword. More historic information: [Why are structure names different from their typedef names?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080326-00/?p=22993) and [Why do structures get tag names even if there is a typedef?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080327-00/?p=22973).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, a `struct` is the same as a `class` (with the exception of the default access modifier). You can assign default values by providing a default constructor. If you are using C++11, you can also use in-class initializers for non-static, non-const class members, e.g.:

```
typedef struct tagReferenceMWB
{
    // ...
    WORD         wCount{ 0 };
    bool         bReferenced{ false };
    bool         bModified{ false };

} S_REFERENCE_MWB;
```

or

```
typedef struct tagReferenceMWB
{
    // ...
    WORD         wCount{};
    bool         bReferenced{};
    bool         bModified{};

} S_REFERENCE_MWB;
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do you find out what C++ version you are compiling with in Visual Studio?

Comment: This is available from the project settings, under C++/Language. If you are using Visual Studio 2019, it defaults to C++14.

Comment: Simply try to compile with in-class initialization. If it compiles, you are using C++11 or later. If it doesn't supply a default constructor: `tagReferenceMWB { tagReferenceMWB() : wCount(0), bReferenced(false), bModified(false) {} /* list of structure members */ }`.

Comment: It does compile with no errors so I am using C++11 or later. I might try changing that setting to C++ 14. See what happens.